# Trying to save word file, from excel vba, without over-writing any existing files

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Trying to save word file, from excel vba, without over-writing any existing files.  The possibility exists that the filename chosen (taken from the spreadsheet) may be a duplicate, in which case I would like to pause or stop the code, but instead it over-writes automatically)  As below, though my two prong attempt to error catch fails, and the word document is over written:

```
Sub automateword()

        Dim fileToOpen As String
        Dim intChoice As Integer
        Dim myFile As Object

        mysheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Set Wst = Workbooks(mysheet).ActiveSheet


    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If intChoice <> 0 Then
'get the file path selected by the user
fileToOpen = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

End If

    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")

    Set myFile = wordapp.documents.Add(fileToOpen)

    i = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(Wst.Cells(i, 2))
        i = i + 1

    Loop
    i = i - 1

    wordapp.Visible = True
    Filename = Wst.Cells(i, 2) + " " + Wst.Cells(i, 3) + Str(Wst.Cells(i, 10))

    On Error GoTo errorline
    wordapp.DisplayAlerts = True
    FullPath = "\\networkpath\" & Filename & ".doc"
    myFile.SaveAs (FullPath)


Exit Sub
errorline:
MsgBox ("filename error")
End Sub
```

Comment: Document.SaveAs will overwrite an existing file without prompt or error. You have to check for the existence of the file first.

Comment: Best error handling strategy is to avoid run-time errors being raised in the first place. Use `Dir` to verify if the file exists before you use that file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this if-statement before adding a word document.

`If Dir(fileToOpen) <> "" Then Exit Sub`