# Word - Prevent SaveAs2 (VBA) from overwriting

Tags: vba, ms-word, overwrite, save-as

Somewhere on the internet I found this code to easily save a .docx file out of a .dotx file into the desired folder:

```
Sub SaveFileInTheCorrectDirectory()
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "[the correct directory, put in manually by me in the VBA code]" & InputBox("Type the desired file name", "Save As")
End Sub
```

However, this code automatically overwrites an already existing file with the same name (and in the same directory, of course). I've tried looking for code to fix this, and found a few suggestions:

- [Trying to save word file, from excel vba, without over-writing any existing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122492/trying-to-save-word-file-from-excel-vba-without-over-writing-any-existing-file)
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-macro-saveas-overights-exsiting-file-without/e6fce3b1-ee72-498d-8fe5-fbc3e0cdbf23
- http://computer-programming-forum.com/1-vba/2fb545278f4311ff.htm
- https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.word.vba.customization/c/Q4W2CK4gQOg?pli=1

But I can't figure out how to implement them...

Could someone be so kind to assist me?

Thanks!

PS Is there added value to use "SaveAs2" instead of "SaveAs" or the other way around?

Comment: Use `FileSystemObject` or `Dir` to detect if file already exists

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to. I'm no expert, just someone fiddling around with what he finds on the internet...

Comment: How is this any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's as simple as:

```
Dim StrName as String
StrName = InputBox("Type the desired file name", "Save As")
If Trim(StrName) = "" then Exit Sub
If Dir(StrPath & StrName & ".docx") = "" Then ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 StrPath & StrName & ".docx"
```

where StrPath & StrName are the path & name, respectively.

**Note**: I haven't added any code for what to do if the file exists because you haven't said what you want to do in that case. Post a new question if you need help with that.

Comment: I think a pop-up with the message that the file already exists, and then the abortion of the saving process would make the most sense... (Or do you mean I have to start an entire new topic?)

Comment: One topic per question. So, yes, if you can't figure out how to construct an 'If' test to pop up a message box (there are many examples here and elsewhere on the web) to do something like that, then start a new topic showing your code and where you're having trouble.